# String literal without need to escape backslash

Tags: ruby, string, literals

In C#, I can write backslashes and other special characters without escaping by using `@` before a string, but I have to escape double-quotes.

**C#**

```
string foo = "The integer division operator in VisualBASIC is written \"a \\ b\"";
string bar = @"The integer division operator in VisualBASIC is written \"a \ b\""
```

In Ruby, I could use the single-quote string literal, but I'd like to use this in conjuction with string interpolation like `"text #{value}"`. Is there an equivalent in Ruby to `@` in C#?

Comment: You will need use `\\` to prepend, there is no equivalent in Rails

Comment: Not clear what you want. A single-quoted string literal in Ruby still requires backslashes to be escaped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is somewhat similar thing available in Ruby. E.g.

```
foo = %Q(The integer division operator in VisualBASIC is written "a \\ b" and #{'interpolation' + ' works'})
```

You can also interpolate strings in it. The only caveat is, you would still need to escape `\` character.

HTH

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to escape the backslash?

Answer (score 4):

You can use heredoc with single quotes.

```
foo = <<'_'
The integer division operator in VisualBASIC is written "a \ b";
_
```

If you want to get rid of the newline character at the end, then `chomp` it.

Note that this does not work with string interpolation. If you want to insert evaluated expressions within the string, you can use `%` operation after you create the string.

```
foo = <<'_'
text %{value}
_

foo.chomp % {value: "foo"}
```

Comment: You would still have to escape `\\` (backslash) AFAIK.

Comment: `foo = <<_
The integer division operator in VisualBASIC is written "a \\ b"; text #{value}
_`. Check double backslashes.

Comment: You can call `chomp` right after the heredoc's opening identifier, i.e.  `foo = <<'_'.chomp ...`